# Actionscript- sortCompare function freezes the application while sorting

Tags: actionscript-3, sorting

I am working on an application which has this AdvancedDataGrid component. One of the columns has Dates in String format (mm/dd/yyyy)- so to sort this according to Dates, I wrote a function to call in that column's sortCompare property:

```
private function sortDueDate(item1: Object, item2: Object): int {

    this.showPleaseWaitMessage();

    // collect the date values as string and convert into Date objects: 
    var date1: Date = new Date(Date.parse(item1.allocationDate));
    var date2: Date = new Date(Date.parse(item2.allocationDate));

    // compare the 2 date objects:
    return ObjectUtil.dateCompare(date1, date2);
}
```

This function works on 5000 rows of data. So obviously it was expected to slow-down or even freeze the application for 5-10 seconds. But this sortCompare function is taking around 40-45 seconds to sort the data. This will certainly confuse the end-user.

So I wrote another function that is called from the above sortDueDate() to display a message- "Please wait while the data is being sorted."

```
private function showPleaseWaitMessage(): void {

    // show message only if this is the 1st iteration:
    if(sortIteration == 1) {  // sortIteration is a private uint only for counting iteration and showing the message at 1st iteration

        formattedAlert = Alert.show("Please wait while the data is being sorted.", "Information", Alert.OK, this, pleaseWaitMessageHandler);
        formattedAlert.styleName = "Alert";

        // set busy cursor:
        CursorManager.setBusyCursor();

        sortIteration++;
    }
    else {

        // do nothing
    }
}

private function pleaseWaitMessageHandler(eventObj: CloseEvent): void {

    // stop busy cursor:
    CursorManager.removeBusyCursor();

    // reset the iteration no. after sorting is complete
    sortIteration = 1;
}
```

All of this look good until I tried running the application. But all the efforts to display a message with a busy-cursor are going in vain, as all this is showing up only after 40-45 seconds of application freezing. And by the time message is displayed, the sorting is completed in background.
I cannot use pagination as our client is against this, surprising but true :-)

Could anyone suggest a work-around for this so that message should be displayed to the user before the sorting starts... Any inputs to handle this situation will be gladly appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally was able to solve issue of application freezing while sorting a column with Date values in TEXT format. The grid had more than 5000 records, and this solution automatically reduced the freezing time to less than 5 seconds (earlier the application was freezing for more than 45 seconds). Here's what I did:

I registered an event listener for the AdvancedDataGrid's HEADER_RELEASE event:

```
dgMyGridHere.addEventListener(AdvancedDataGridEvent.HEADER_RELEASE, startSorting);
```

Then in the listener method, I just checked if the no.of records were more than 1000 (sorting for around 1000 records is done in a flash, so no need to show a message to the user).

```
    /**
     * FUNCTION TO HANDLE THE COLUMN-SORT EVENT.
     **/
    private function startSorting(event: AdvancedDataGridEvent): void {

        // show message to user with busy cursor only if row-count is > 1000 
        if(orgData.length > 1000) {

            this.showPleaseWaitMessage();

            // set busy cursor:
            CursorManager.setBusyCursor();

            // set timer to 5 secs, so that busy cursor is removed after 5 seconds:
            timer = new Timer(5000, 1);
            timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, removeBusyCursor);
            timer.start();
        }
        else {

            // no need to show message
        }

        var sortEvent:AdvancedDataGridEvent = new AdvancedDataGridEvent(AdvancedDataGridEvent.SORT);
        dgAnnualAdvisoryMeeting.dispatchEvent(sortEvent);
    }



    /**
     * FUNCTION TO SHOW A "PLEASE WAIT" MESSAGE.
     **/
    private function showPleaseWaitMessage(): void {

        formattedAlert = Alert.show("Please wait while the data is being sorted.", "Information");
        formattedAlert.styleName = "Alert";
    }
```

I also set the timer for 5 secs to remove the busy cursor (just to let the user know that the sorting is completed- although it is taking less than 5 seconds), here is the timer listener event handler:

```
    /**
     * FUNCTION TO HANDLE THE 5 SECONDS TIMER EVENT AND STOP THE BUSY CURSOR.
     **/
    private function removeBusyCursor(timerEvent: TimerEvent): void {

        // stop busy cursor:
        CursorManager.removeBusyCursor();
    }
```

And that's it! I hope this helps anyone facing similar issue.
Thanks to Peter who provided me an insight into "The Frame" of processing, but I sorted out the issue the other way :-)
Also had inputs from "Christofer Dutz" in his post:

https://dev.c-ware.de/confluence/display/PUBLIC/Programatically+sort+AdvancedDataGrid+columns

Answer (score 2):

The reason the UI is locking up is because Flash uses a single threaded event loop. Each cycle consists of several stages in which system events are dispatched, event handlers are called, and finally rendering is performed. If your code doesn't release control to Flash in a timely manner, then the whole application appears frozen.

Here is a great article that illustrates this concept: [Elastic Racetrack for Flash 9 and AVM2](http://www.craftymind.com/2008/04/18/updated-elastic-racetrack-for-flash-9-and-avm2/)

There are a few solutions. The easiest is to just allow the application to lock up while showing wait message (if you are okay with the application freezing for 45 seconds). To do this we need to allow the Flash player to render before performing the sort. To accomplish this you can create an `ENTER_FRAME` event handler to invoke your logic at the beginning of the next frame (after your code has added the wait message to the `DisplayList`). For example:

```
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, myFunction);
function myFunction(event:Event) {
   // invoke sort logic here
}
```

Another solution (using this concept) is to break up the sort into smaller chunks of work which can spread over several frames, thus allowing the event loop to cycle.

However, the ideal solution would be to leverage the new Worker capabilities of Flash Player 12. This allows you to perform your processing in a separate thread of execution. This works by invoking the worker from your main application code (providing it with the data it needs) and adding an event listener to respond once the job has completed—thus never locking up your main event loop. For more information on workers read here: [Worker  - AS3](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Worker.html)

Comment: Thanks Peter, your post has provided an insight into "The Frame". Will try out this and get back with the results. Just a question though- stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, myFunction);  Here the stage is an object of Application or some thing else?

Comment: @AdwaitDeshpande, the `stage` property is a member of `DisplayObject` and it's subclasses. However, it is not necessary to attach to the `stage`, you can just call `addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, myFunction);` on any sub-class of `DisplayObject`.